# Process time data with adjustments for DST

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a dataset with data for every hour of 5 years. Every data point has a date - I want to include a column that specifies the number of hour, i.e., 00-01 is hour #1, 01-02 is hour #2 and so forth.

However, the dataset includes summer/winter time, i.e., some day in March has a blank hour due to setting forward time with an hour. Furthermore, it includes a day a year that contains 25 hours due to setting back time for winter.

Can anyone help me make a column that counts 1-24 for every day, that still accounts for the summer/winter time. I was thinking something with a counter that continuously counts how many times a date has occurred "so far"

Desired output:

```
          Date  Year  Month  Day  Weekday  Hour
0   01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4     1
1   01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4     2
2   01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4     3
3   01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4     4
4   01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4     5
5   01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4     6
6   01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4     7
7   01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4     8
8   01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4     9
9   01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4    10
10  01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4    11
11  01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4    12
12  01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4    13
13  01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4    14
14  01-01-2015  2015      1    1        4    15
```

```
           Dates  Year  Month  Weekday  Hour  ...    NO1    NO2    NO5    NO3    NO4
2088  29-03-2015  2015      3        7     1  ...  22.90  22.90  22.90  22.90  22.90
2089  29-03-2015  2015      3        7     2  ...  22.37  22.37  22.37  22.37  22.37
2090  29-03-2015  2015      3        7     3  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2091  29-03-2015  2015      3        7     4  ...  21.94  21.94  21.94  22.03  22.03
2092  29-03-2015  2015      3        7     5  ...  21.52  21.52  21.52  22.01  22.01
```

```
           Dates  Year  Month  Weekday  Hour  ...    NO1    NO2    NO5    NO3    NO4
7128  25-10-2015  2015     10        7     1  ...  22.39  22.39  22.39  22.39  22.39
7129  25-10-2015  2015     10        7     2  ...  22.02  22.02  22.02  21.54  21.54
7130  25-10-2015  2015     10        7     3  ...  21.99  21.99  21.99  20.82  20.82
7131  25-10-2015  2015     10        7     4  ...  21.99  21.99  21.99  20.77  20.77
7132  25-10-2015  2015     10        7     5  ...  21.80  21.80  21.80  20.11  20.11
```

Comment: if you dont need daylight savings in your data, cant you just remove that from your dataset by shifting dates between march and october by 1 hour

Comment: I'm downloading the dataset directly from the website, so the method has to be dynamic enough to be able the handle the daylight savings

Comment: You need to know the rules for DST in the locale where the data was generated; then normalizing everything to UTC should be easy.

Comment: I know that it changes on the last Sunday of March and last Sunday of October - I don't know how to convert that though

Comment: Added an example of the issue - you can see that while the day is 7 (Sunday) the hours do not fit since it is a simple repeat of the values 1-24.
Here every column is made from df.dt.year/month/weekday.
I'm in GMT+2

Comment: Thanks for the update; but I have to ask for clarification once more. Could you change the data sample to show how the data looks for 2015-10-25, hour 1-5 (DST transition +1 hour) as well as 2015-03-29, hour 1-5 (DST transition -1 hour)? Also, just to be sure, GMT+2 is a UTC offset - what is the [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)?

Comment: I've added what I think you're asking for. Well, I guess the time zone would be Europe/Copenhagen then - not really something I'm used to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd drop rows with `NaN` values since these originate from a non-existent hour (DST transition):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# mre / dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ["29-03-2015", "29-03-2015", "29-03-2015", "29-03-2015", "29-03-2015",
             "25-10-2015", "25-10-2015", "25-10-2015", "25-10-2015", "25-10-2015"],
    'Value': [1, 2, np.NaN, 4, 5,
              1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    })

# drop all rows with NaN values; adjust if needed!
df = df.dropna()
```

Now you can recalculate the hour based on the date:

```
# recalculate the hour of day, zero-based
datechange = df['Date'].eq(df['Date'].shift())
df['Hour_New'] = datechange.cumsum() - datechange.cumsum().where(~datechange).ffill()

# df
#          Date  Value  Hour_New
# 0  29-03-2015    1.0       0.0
# 1  29-03-2015    2.0       1.0
# 3  29-03-2015    4.0       2.0
# 4  29-03-2015    5.0       3.0
# 5  25-10-2015    1.0       0.0
# 6  25-10-2015    2.0       1.0
# 7  25-10-2015    3.0       2.0
# 8  25-10-2015    4.0       3.0
# 9  25-10-2015    5.0       4.0
```

...which enables you to calculate time zone aware datetime:

```
zone = 'Europe/Copenhagen'
# begin with date, localized to origin time zone
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.tz_localize(zone)
# now add the hour as a timedelta
df['datetime'] += pd.to_timedelta(df['Hour_New'], unit='h')

# df['datetime']
# 0   2015-03-29 00:00:00+01:00
# 1   2015-03-29 01:00:00+01:00
# 3   2015-03-29 03:00:00+02:00 # <-- one hour stolen due to DST transition
# 4   2015-03-29 04:00:00+02:00
# 5   2015-10-25 00:00:00+02:00
# 6   2015-10-25 01:00:00+02:00
# 7   2015-10-25 02:00:00+02:00
# 8   2015-10-25 02:00:00+01:00 # <-- duplicate hour due to DST transition
# 9   2015-10-25 03:00:00+01:00
# Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Copenhagen]
```

Comment: Thank you. With a tiny amount of editing (converting back to just an hour) after doing this did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert the column in to a datetime and then extract the hour from the datetime?

then drop any hours that are 0 or 25, making all your days 24 hours long.

Hint use pandas datetime to convert column to datetime and then use the hour function to make a new column.

Comment: First, I can convert to datetime - but the data does not contain hour-stamp - I don't know how to convert to hour if the original data does not include hour-stamps. 
And I would still keep the hours - I just need to know that the hours fits after 3 years as well as the first
The .hour function just returns 0s

Comment: you cannot even convert to datetime if the hour is 25 - only hours from 0 - 23 are allowed here.

Comment: Which is why I started out asking to help me make some sort of counter that could count the number of occurrences of a specific date "until now"-ish. Like "how many times have the date in this row been seen between this row and the first row. Does that make sense?